# Improving speed on edge weight computation in graph Igraph R

Tags: r, igraph

I have a simple problem. I am trying to set the weight of the edges in a graph that I want to make some computations on.
My working code is as follows:
 
`for(e in E(g)){
    E(g)[e]$weight <- 1/(degree(g, v = V(g)[ends(g, e)][2], mode = "in"))
}`
For small graphs this works fine.
But for a graph that has 105K edges this takes way too long (65 mins!!)
Is there a more efficient way to do this, how can I make this faster?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the computations far faster by vectorizing the code, thus avoiding the for loop entirely -- which is re-computing the degree of each node more frequently than it needs to:

```r
library(igraph)

# A small toy graph to demonstrate
set.seed(234)
g <- random.graph.game(10, .25, directed = T)

# Your approach for constructing weights
for(e in E(g)){
  E(g)[e]$weight <- 1/(degree(g, v = V(g)[ends(g, e)][2], mode = "in"))
}

# Vectorized version
res <- 1/degree(g, v = V(g)[ends(g, E(g))[,2]], mode = "in")

# We test to make sure the results are the same
all.equal(E(g)$weight, res)
#> [1] TRUE

# To show how much faster it is lets make a big graph with ~100k edges
set.seed(42)
g <- random.graph.game(1000, .1, directed = T)
length(E(g))
#> [1] 99307

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(E(g)$weight <- 1/degree(g, v = V(g)[ends(g, E(g))[,2]], mode = "in"))
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                                                                   expr
#>  E(g)$weight <- 1/degree(g, v = V(g)[ends(g, E(g))[, 2]], mode = "in")
#>       min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>  15.45099 57.88469 54.22476 59.22422 60.43034 106.6269   100
```

The new version takes about 60 milliseconds on 99,307 edges.